# angular 2 form local

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have form like:

```
<form  #testForm="ngForm" (submit)="create(testForm)">
    <input type="text" [value]="111" ng-control="test">
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

but when I `console.log` `testForm` in there is no `test` key (and `testForm.value` is undefined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two thing, `(submit)` should be `(ngSubmit)` and `ng-control` should be `ngControl`. Also using `[value]` to set an initial value wont work, use `[(ngModel)]` with an initial value instead.

Here's an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qi08ZTgFWH2WpHWre7qu

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="create()" [ngFormModel]="form" #testForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" ngControl="test">
</form>
```

the `form` instance in my sample is defined in the component code.

Here is a working form demo/article if you need it as well:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/form

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/forms-and-validation-in-angular-2.0